# How to call an ant target / maven after JBoss Tools Deploy?

Tags: eclipse, maven, ant, jboss6.x, jboss-tools

Is there any possibility to run ant after, let's say a clean of a jboss tools server?

e.g. i plan to move some directories after having deployed them to a different directory to speed up things in jboss start up.

Another solution which came to my mind was to make jboss tools call a specific "start jboss" task/bat/something which would result in first calling my own 'move files' target then starting jboss

**[EDIT - solved]**

So the working solution for me was a comination of ant and jboss tools.

I use jboss 6.0.0 and jboss tools 3.2 i think

So double click the jboss 6.0.0 server, click on the tab deployment (it's a usability fail imho that this important tab is at the bottom of the view/window).
Now click on your dynamic web app module name in the list. Redirect the deployment location to yourwebappname.ear/yourwebappname.war
Use the jboss deploy folder
Move all lib files from the war/web-inf/lib to yourweappname.ear/lib 
I could move all of them except spring-web-2.5.6.jar
Delete them in web-inf
eventually create and fill the meta-inf directory in yourwebappname.ear/META-INF (i did it at least) with application.xml and manifest.mf

thanks @ sir Andersen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not reveal what kind of moves you exactly want to do and no, there is no direct support to call out to Ant or similar after a clean in JBoss Tools deploy.

But depending on what you actually want to do one or more of the below options might work for you:

**Use custom deploy directory for the server**
If you just need all deployments go to a specific directory then just set a custom deploy directory for the server - no need to move anything.
This is done by double clicking on the server and in the server editor under the deployments tab you can control the root directory.

**Use custom deploy directory and name for specific deployments**
If you need more finegrained control then you can also use the Deployments page described above to set the relative directory and name for deployment for each individual module.

**Have a Ant task setup as eclipse external tool builder**
If none of the above works then you could setup an Ant task as external tool builder under Project Properties. This ant launcher you can even limit to only run when certain resources changes inside the eclipse workspace - you might be able to use that to control when you want to do the "move some directories".

Comment: What I want to do in detail is move the files from the folder mywebapp.war/WebContent/Web-Inf/Lib to mywebapp.ear/lib and all files from mywebapp.war to mywebapp.ear/mywebapp.war. Reason for doing so see here http://community.jboss.org/message/642919#642919 - bottom line: it speeds up jboss start from well over 2 minutes to 40 seconds. Sooo thanks very much for your answer - I didn't know it's possbile to change Deployment Location in the Deployment View - you have to first select the corresponding Module to be able to change it. Thanks